# button click is not working in jquery dialog box after adding some dynamic styles to it

Tags: jquery, html

i need to show one dynamic dialog box with 2 option continue and close in chat window if user clicks continue it should continue in same window is user click close it should close (basically reloading page will close) continue work fine but close is not working 
code i  have tried is in jquery is

```
 <div id="cont_close" title="<c:out value="do you continue or close "/>">
</div>

$( function() {
    $( "#cont_close" ).dialog({
        resizable: false, 
        height: "auto",
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons:  {
            "1":{
                id:'continue',
                text:jsonLabels.WINDOW_CONTINUE,
                click: function() {
                    AgentConnectedChat = false;
                    processChatRequest();
                    $( this ).dialog("close");
                },
                "class":"colordialog"
            },
            "2":{
                id:'close',
                text:jsonLabels.WINDOW_CLOSE,
                click: function() {
                    closechatwindow();
                    $( this ).dialog("close");
                },
                "class":"colordialog"
            }
        }
    });
} );
```

and i am adding dynamic styles if user pass hexcode param as query parameter 
flow works fine if i dont pass query parameter,if i pass hexcode parameter styles are applied but close click event not working

```
    if(hexcode!=null && hexcode!=undefined)
    {
            if(document.getElementById("close")!=null &&
               document.getElementById("close")!=undefined)
            {
                document.getElementById("close").className = "colordialog1";
                document.getElementById("close").style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
                document.getElementById("close").style.borderColor = hexcode;
            }
            if(document.getElementById("continue")!=null &&
               document.getElementById("continue")!=undefined)
             {
                document.getElementById("continue").className = "colordialog1";
                    document.getElementById("continue").style.backgroundColor = hexcode;
document.getElementById("continue").style.borderColor = hexcode;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please replace the jstl codesnippet by the represented html value.

Comment: How do you "close" this div? What happens if you remove the jstl code snippet from your div element?

Comment: i am just reloading page with window.location href so reloading will take me to first page

Comment: i think i found cause its bcz of #,when i pass query param like hexcode=#000FF its not reloading page if i dont pass # then its reloading, so what i did is removed # from param value and reloading page with out query param..but can any one tell me why its creating problem when i pass # is it converting '#' to any values